# Can't install USB driver for Zopo ZP300+ on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: usb-drivers, mediatek

When I enabled USB debugging in settings for Zopo ZP300+, an unrecognized device appeared in device manager: H9000+.

Then I followed this: https://web.archive.org/web/20160918125953/http://www.zopomobileshop.com:80/zopo-rom/how-to-install-driver-for-zopo-mobile-phone-step-by-step-instruction/. MT65XX Preloader replaced with "MediaTek PreLoader USB VCOM Port (COM3)", then it disappeared. I unplugged the USB, turned on the phone, and plugged it back in. No new drivers were installed. H9000+ is still unrecognized. Eclipse says: No compatible targets were found.

Comment: You might want to try Koush's [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong driver. H9000+ means you need ZOPO MTK6577 DRIVER.